# Vectorization of loops in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp, vectorization

I am writing a program in C (a 2d poisson solver) and I am using openMP to speed-up a  big for loop. What I observed is that inside an openMP parallel block, the for loop is not vectorized even in the case where I include the *#pragma always vector* directive. For the compilation I am using the pathscale compiler.

The code I want to vectorize looks like this :

```
  #pragma omp parallel shared(in, out, lambda,dim,C) private(k)
     {
            #pragma omp for  schedule(guided,dim/nthreads)  nowait  
            for(k = 0;k < dim; k++){
                    in[k]  = C*out[k]*lambda[k];
            }
    }
```

where out,lambda and in are double precision arrays.

But even if I include *#pragma always vector*, what the compiler answers is :

```
 warning: ignoring #pragma always vector
```

Do you know if there is any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm tempted to think that you won't get much from vectorizing/parallelizing that loop. There's so little work for a lot of memory access.

Comment: @Mysticial, this was part of an entry for a contest and it did help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through [the User Guide for the PathScale compiler](http://www.pathscale.com/docs/UserGuide.pdf), and did not find neither `#pragma always` nor `#pragma vector`. So I think the compiler just tells you that it does not recognize this pragma, and ignores it.

However in section 7.4.5 I found the following options that should help you with vectorization:

> Vectorization of user code ... is controlled  by the flag `-LNO:simd[=(0|1|2)]`, which enables or disables inner loop  vectorization. 0 turns off the vectorizer, 1 (the default) causes the compiler to  vectorize only if it can determine that there is no undesirable performance impact  due to sub-optimal alignment, and 2 will vectorize without any constraints (this is  the most aggressive).
>
> `-LNO:simd_verbose=ON` prints vectorizer information (from vectorizing user  code) to stdout.

As a side note (guessing where you could take that `#pragma always vector` from), [Intel's compiler has `#pragma vector`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/mac/cref_cls/common/cppref_pragma_vector.htm) with `always` being one possible parameter to the pragma. But pragmas are generally compiler-specific, except for few extensions (OpenMP being one) that are supported by multiple vendors.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I just found it out myself and tried it but like Mysticial said, the work isn't enough it seems for it to make that much of a difference.